# Export fluid simulation from Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-5

I’ve searched around, I can see different options to import Alembic animations for simulation from different software (e.g. Blender), but I see no options for exporting fluid simulation (Niagara fluid) from Unreal Engine. Is this not possible?

Comment: I've been told that you can sample the 3D textures, but they wouldn't tell me how. They wanted me to pay the $1500 USD/year for the Pro contract.

I basically had an idea for a shmup game, and I could use Niagara for fire and lightning, but there was no way to tell if the enemies are in the danger zone. Kind of like a car with 2 wheels. Very not useful.

Comment: @shawn_halayka , Hmm..., but, if you plan to do things in unreal, there might be workarounds, however, there doesn't seem to be a way to get things out of unreal